# How to encode blob to base64 string on yii framework?

Tags: php, mysql, yii, base64, blob

I want to encode blob image from DB to base64 string, then I want to encode the string with JSON.
I've tried this:

```
$img = Image::model()->findBySql('SELECT img FROM tbl_img WHERE id=1');
$value = chunk_split(base64_encode($img));
echo CJSON::encode($value);
```

The img field above is blob. And I've got nothing. Can anyone help? 
Thanks

Comment: why the chunksplit? If you're encoding to json, just encode the raw base64 string.

Comment: so, would you edit the code above for me? I'm new with yii. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
echo json_encode($value);
```

Instead of

```
echo CJSON::encode($value);
```

Comment: is that the problem? how do you think about chunk_split and encoding the blob?.  Thanks anyway.